# Applying a gate to all line qubits without explicitly listing them in Cirq

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, circuit-construction, cirq

Say we have a custom gate `CG`, defined by a unitary matrix `U`, and line qubits `qubits` in Cirq. Something like this:

```
import numpy
import cirq

U = np.eye(8)    # The custom unitary matrix goes here
CG = cirq.MatrixGate(U)
qubits = cirq.LineQubit.range(3)
```

We build the circuit as follows:

```
circuit = cirq.Circuit()
circuit.append(CG(qubits[0], qubits[1], qubits[2]))
```

Is it possible to build the circuit without explicitly specifying all the qubits? Something like `circuit.append(CG(qubits))`, which would apply the `CG` gate to all the qubits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you can say `callable(*args)` instead of `callable(args[0], args[1], args[2])`.

Comment: i.e. in your example you could write `CG(*qubits)`